# Как сделать автообновление контента на сайте?

Tags: javascript, django, веб-программирование

хочу сделать новостной сайт, и тут возникла проблема, как сделать автообновление статей на сайте, например что бы текст в контейнер  менялся со временем (парсить текст с одного сайта, на другой сайт). я представлю как это можно реализовать с помощью Django но можно ли сделать такой функционал на JS что бы сам сайт был легче ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идёт о реальном времени: понадобится парсер, WebSocket-сервер, и подключить сайт к WebSocket-серверу. Когда парсер находит и добавляет новую статью, он сообщает об этом WebSocket-серверу, и тот рассылает всем кто находится на сайте запрос, что нужно загрузить информацию о новой статье, и она в режиме реального времени появляется.

Либо если обновление в реальном времени излишне - достаточно будет парсера, который будет добавлять/изменять данные в БД, а сайт просто будет подтягивать эти данные.

Это самый оптимальный путь к решению.

И парсер, и websocket-сервер, и сайт можно написать на javascript (но это не единственный вариант разумеется)